# Dot Net Nuke issue with new page visible to Admin Only in Nav

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have an issue with DotNetNuke where only the admin can see a new page I've added in the main navigation (the page appears in sidebar for all users)

After creating a new page with DotNetNuke, I can manually browse to the page, and all links to it work however it is only visible in the navigation menu when I'm logged in as administrator.

Manually going to the page works fine when not logged in. Include in Menu? is checked (and been toggled) and I've tried all variations of permissions I can think of (which apart from the navigation issue work exactly as I would expect).

I hope this is the correct format I'm still relatively new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have the page settings set to admin only for view... navigate to the page click on pages>page settings. click on the permissions tab and make sure inherit page settings from parent page is unchecked. Then next to All Users, Registered Users, Subscriber,
Translator (en-US), Unauthenticated Users and Unverified Users  make sure there is a green check mark in the view section. Then make sure that page is disabled in advanced settings is unchecked and include in menu in page settings is checked.... Hope this helps... If not try making a new page and copy all the modules from the old one and see if that works

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did try checking all those things after your post to no avail.

I did manage to solve the error eventually by doing a cache wipe and reset consecutively (clearing just cache had no effect).

Comment: Also of course the solution comes right after I ask here >.<

Comment: That's how it always happens!